# How to list all styles in zsh

Tags: zsh

How an I list all of the styles defined in a zsh session using the `zstyle` command? I would like to know this so I know what configuration options are available to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`zstyle -L` lists all the styles that have been defined, with their values. For a slightly nicer display with only the patterns, you can use

```
zstyle-list-patterns () {
  local tmp
  zstyle -g tmp
  print -rl -- "${(@o)tmp}"
}
```

This is a far cry from your goal of listing all the styles that you can configure. For one thing, styles can be based on wildcards, which can be instantiated in infinitely many ways (for example, completion settings can be set per command).

There is no declaration of styles: a function that can be configured through a style calls the `zstyle` command to look up some value, possibly with variable arguments. It's impossible to anticipate what arguments are going to be passed to `zstyle` in the future. All you can do is consult the documentation of the function (when it exists) or its source code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess it is really unfortunate that I have to consult the documentation/src of a function to determine how it uses styles.

Comment: I would guess that since autocompletion works for the `zstyle` command, that you could at least query that somehow: `zstyle ':[Hit Tab]`

Comment: @MattAlexander Good point, that's another method, which is mostly based on hard-coded lists for each field (and some dynamic generation for a few parts). So that'll give you a subset of what can be configured for the functions shipped with zsh.